# Hide popcorn elements in a div

Tags: popcornjs

So with popcorn.js you specify the div that your footnotes, etc. will populate. If you have more than one video that is using the same div for said footnotes, however, when you switch videos while a footnote is popped, it remains in the div and the next element will get placed below it, rather than replace it. I can't use a .html(' ') because all the elements are actually always there, just being shown and hidden in order. Can't hide the whole div, either.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple ways to do this.

One option is to create two div's within that same div, with each having a CSS style of `position: absolute` and the parent div having `position: relative`. The two divs will overlap each other, and you can have each one be the target for all the footnotes in a different Popcorn instance. When you switch between the two videos, set `display: none` on the div for the hidden video and clear it for the visible one.

Another trick I often use for this sort of thing is to use `.disable`. That will hide all the footnotes for that popcorn instance. Something like this:

```
function activateVideo(index) {
  if (activePopcorn) {
      activePopcorn.disable('footnote');
      //todo: make this video invisible.
  }

  activePopcorn = popcornInstances[index];
  activePopcorn.enable('footnote');
  //todo: make this video visible.
  //(don't forget to range check)
}
```

If you want, you can disable/enable all plugins by looping through `Popcorn.registryByName`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Neither of these are ideal and it's a shame they haven't introduced a simple way to do this in code. Just a quick #pop.popcornClear() function :(

Comment: Just want to make sure I'm not misunderstanding. Do you want to permanently remove all the footnotes? Or just temporarily?

Comment: Just temporarily, so that I can have multiple videos using the same div to spit out footnotes, wiki articles, etc. Then when the user wants to watch another video, the footnote etc div gets cleared so that when the new video pops something, it doesn't look like ITEM1 with ITEM2 directly underneath it. If it helps, I have a working demo of my project @ http://graysonearle.com/communityliving/ So if you watch the home video until something pops up, then click the tree (on the house image) and play that vid, the first pop from that ends up directly below the original pop.

Comment: Calling enable and disable on every plugin should solve your problem. Popcorn doesn't have a single method to do this, but you can easily write it as a reusable function yourself. You may consider posting a feature request to disable/enable *all* plugins if no parameter is passed to the method. https://webmademovies.lighthouseapp.com/dashboard